Install R packages “DescTools’ Warning message: installation of package ‘DescTools’ had non-zero exit status
When installing the package“DescTools”, the following error message shown:
ERROR: dependency ‘expm’ is not available for package ‘DescTools’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/library/DescTools’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘DescTools’ had non-zero exit status

The RStudio version is 2023.12.1+402.
What to do next?
I tried to install the DescTools and Expam agian, and asked if choose the version with compilation, I entered YES, let it install again. It finished installation, but when I requrie the package again, there is the error messages repeat everytime.

The RStudio version is irrelevant. The R version, the package version, the OS (and the compiler) are relevant. It looks like you are using a mac? Why don't you update to the newest R version and use the prebuild package binaries (i.e., not install from source)?

ERROR: dependency ‘expm’ is not available for package ‘DescTools’ - you have to check why {expm} was not installed or try to install it prior to {DescTools}. Please provide whole log of {expm} installation.


require(DescTools)
Loading required package: DescTools
Warning message:
In library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,  :
there is no package called ‘DescTools’



require(DescTools)
Loading required package: DescTools
Warning message:
In library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,  :
there is no package called ‘DescTools’


I've updated to the latest R version, and try to install again, but the above warning message appeared again.
